# OperationContextScope with web reference

Tags: c#, web-services

Using a `service reference` i have this:

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)) {
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpDetails;
    return predicate(client);
}
```

I want to know how can i do the same with a **web reference** instead of **service reference**. Using web reference the property `InnerChannel` doesn't exist.

There is some way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "web reference" you mean a reference to an ASMX based web service then it cannot be done. A "service reference" creates a WCF based proxy in your client app to the service. A "web reference" creates a service proxy using the old .NET 1.1 days XML Web Service framework (ASMX). The `OperationContextScope` is only available to the WCF client.

The fix is to create a "service reference" instead of a "web reference" to the service in question. That way, the proxy to both services will be WCF based and you can use `OperationContextScope` for both. WCF is backward compatible to any ASMX based service.

Comment: This works! I used the "service reference" instead and now i can use the OperationContextScope like i want. Thanks!